# Разобрать команду git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages (Github Pages)?

Tags: git

При "пуше" на Github pages требуется пыполнить такую команду

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

Можете ее расшифровать? Что значит каждое слово и общий смысл

Comment: Нет, выполнять такую команду не требуется. Для использования GitHub Pages достаточно включить его в настройках репозитория, да выбрать ветку и папку внутри которой размешены файлы вашего статического сайта.

Comment: subtree - "средство" автоматизации работы с поддеревьями, дополнительно указывается префикс (директорию) `--prefix dist`, а остальное как в обычной команде